# Specific kanji gets wrongly encoded during http get request

Tags: php, mongodb, http, utf-8, phalcon

I am having a really weird encoding issue when using kanji for the application I am developing; all kanji characters except the character "免" work fine.
When I try to use this character, mongodb throws the following exception:

```
Exception: non-utf8 string: �
```

Any other kanji character works fine.

I have tried to remove the functions processing the string, and input it directly to the function handling mongodb but to no success.
I have also tried to convert the character from various encodings, but to no avail.

This is what I am using:

- Phalcon 2.0 - https://phalconphp.com
- Apache 2.4.12
- PHP 5.6.8
- MongoDB 3.0.4

Thanks!

**Controller function handling the request**

```
public function kanjiAction($findKanji = "")
{
    // Really weird issue with the kanji 免 not working

    $findKanji = $this->filter->sanitize($findKanji, 'string');
    $findKanji = mb_substr($findKanji, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');

    $kanjiHash = md5($findKanji);

    // If entry does not exist in cache, create it
    if(!$this->viewCache->exists($kanjiHash)) {

        // Get data from DB
        $kanji = Kanji::findById($findKanji);

        $words = Words::containingKanji($findKanji);

        $showWords = array();

        foreach ($words as $word) {
            foreach ($word->k_ele["keb"] as $key => $value) {
                if(strpos($value, $findKanji) != false) {
                    $showWords[] = (object) array(
                        "word" => $value,
                        "readings" => $word->r_ele["reb"],
                        "meanings" => $word->sense["gloss"]
                    );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Fetch translations
        $this->view->onTitle = $this->translation->query('onTitle');
        $this->view->kunTitle = $this->translation->query('kunTitle');
        $this->view->radicalTitle = $this->translation->query('radicalTitle');
        $this->view->meaningsTitle = $this->translation->query('meaningsTitle');
        $this->view->strokeCountTitle = $this->translation->query('strokeCountTitle');
        $this->view->jlptTitle = $this->translation->query('jlptTitle');
        $this->view->containsWordsTitle = $this->translation->query('containsWordsTitle');
        $this->view->readingsTitle = $this->translation->query('readingsTitle');
        $this->view->wordsTitle = $this->translation->query('wordsTitle');
        $this->view->notFound = $this->translation->query('notFound');

        // Pass data to view
        $this->view->kanji = $kanji->_id;
        if(isset($kanji->reading["on"]) && count($kanji->reading["on"]) > 0)
            $this->view->onReadings = $kanji->reading["on"];
        if(isset($kanji->reading["kun"]) && count($kanji->reading["kun"]) > 0)
            $this->view->kunReadings = $kanji->reading["kun"];
        if(isset($kanji->radicals))
            $this->view->radicals = $kanji->radicals;
        if(isset($kanji->attributes['jlpt']))
            $this->view->jlpt = $kanji->attributes['jlpt'];
        if(isset($kanji->attributes['stroke_count']))
            $this->view->strokeCount = $kanji->attributes['stroke_count'];
        if(isset($kanji->meaning))
            $this->view->meanings = $kanji->meaning;
        if(count($showWords) > 0) 
            $this->view->words = $showWords;

        $this->view->kanjiHash = $kanjiHash;
    } else {
        $this->view->kanjiHash = $kanjiHash;
    }
}
```

**Request Header for non-working kanji:**

```
GET /view/kanji/%E5%85%8D HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

**Response header for non-working kanji:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 03 Jul 2015 13:04:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.8
Content-Length: 29
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

**Request Header for working kanji:**

```
GET /view/kanji/%E5%A8%A9 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

**Response header for working kanji:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 03 Jul 2015 13:16:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.8
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Edit:

Stack trace for 免:

```
#0 [internal function]: MongoCursor->rewind()
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Collection::_getResultset(Array, Object(Purple\Model\Kanji), Object(MongoDB), true)
#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Collection::findFirst(Array)
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\app\Purple\Controller\ViewController.php(33): Phalcon\Mvc\Collection::findById('\xE5')
#4 [internal function]: Purple\Controller\ViewController->kanjiAction('\xE5')
#5 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#6 E:\xampp\htdocs\public\index.php(98): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#7 {main}
```

Edit 2:

```
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.294298 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f045c0/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] add path info postfix: E:/xampp/htdocs/view -> E:/xampp/htdocs/view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.294798 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f045c0/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d -> view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.294798 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f045c0/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '^$' to uri 'view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d'
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.294798 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f045c0/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] add path info postfix: E:/xampp/htdocs/view -> E:/xampp/htdocs/view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.294798 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f045c0/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d -> view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.294798 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f045c0/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d'
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.294798 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f045c0/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] rewrite 'view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d' -> 'public/view/kanji/\xe5'
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.294798 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f045c0/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] add per-dir prefix: public/view/kanji/\xe5 -> E:/xampp/htdocs/public/view/kanji/\xe5
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.294798 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f045c0/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] strip document_root prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/public/view/kanji/\xe5 -> /public/view/kanji/\xe5
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.294798 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f045c0/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] internal redirect with /public/view/kanji/\xe5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.296799 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f06278/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] add path info postfix: E:/xampp/htdocs/public/view -> E:/xampp/htdocs/public/view/kanji/\xe5
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.296799 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f06278/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/public/view/kanji/\xe5 -> view/kanji/\xe5
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.317801 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f06278/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'view/kanji/\xe5'
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.318301 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f06278/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] rewrite 'view/kanji/\xe5' -> 'index.php?_url=/view/kanji/\xe5'
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.318301 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f06278/initial/redir#1] split uri=index.php?_url=/view/kanji/\xe5 -> uri=index.php, args=_url=/view/kanji/\xe5
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.318301 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f06278/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> E:/xampp/htdocs/public/index.php
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.318301 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f06278/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] strip document_root prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/public/index.php -> /public/index.php
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.318301 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f06278/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] internal redirect with /public/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.318301 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f0d7d8/initial/redir#2] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/public/index.php -> index.php
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.318301 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f0d7d8/initial/redir#2] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
[Mon Jul 06 18:05:59.318801 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5728:tid 2180] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:52741] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#3dac08][rid#3f0d7d8/initial/redir#2] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] pass through E:/xampp/htdocs/public/index.php
```

Edit 3:

```
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.844429 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f240c8/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] add path info postfix: E:/xampp/htdocs/view -> E:/xampp/htdocs/view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.844429 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f240c8/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d -> view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.844429 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f240c8/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '^$' to uri 'view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d'
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.844429 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f240c8/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] add path info postfix: E:/xampp/htdocs/view -> E:/xampp/htdocs/view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.844429 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f240c8/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d -> view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.844929 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f240c8/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d'
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.844929 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f240c8/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] rewrite 'view/kanji/\xe5\x85\x8d' -> 'public/view%2fkanji%2f%e5'
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.844929 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f240c8/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] add per-dir prefix: public/view%2fkanji%2f%e5 -> E:/xampp/htdocs/public/view%2fkanji%2f%e5
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.844929 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f240c8/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] strip document_root prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/public/view%2fkanji%2f%e5 -> /public/view%2fkanji%2f%e5
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.844929 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f240c8/initial] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/] internal redirect with /public/view%2fkanji%2f%e5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.849429 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f25e28/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] add path info postfix: E:/xampp/htdocs/public/view -> E:/xampp/htdocs/public/view/kanji/\xe5
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.849429 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f25e28/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/public/view/kanji/\xe5 -> view/kanji/\xe5
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.849429 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f25e28/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'view/kanji/\xe5'
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.849429 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f25e28/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] rewrite 'view/kanji/\xe5' -> 'index.php?_url=/view%2fkanji%2f%e5'
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.849429 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f25e28/initial/redir#1] split uri=index.php?_url=/view%2fkanji%2f%e5 -> uri=index.php, args=_url=/view%2fkanji%2f%e5
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.849429 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f25e28/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> E:/xampp/htdocs/public/index.php
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.849429 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f25e28/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] strip document_root prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/public/index.php -> /public/index.php
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.849429 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f25e28/initial/redir#1] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] internal redirect with /public/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.849930 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f2d448/initial/redir#2] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/xampp/htdocs/public/index.php -> index.php
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.849930 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f2d448/initial/redir#2] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
[Tue Jul 07 01:25:18.850430 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 7480:tid 2176] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:63967] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#5fac08][rid#3f2d448/initial/redir#2] [perdir E:/xampp/htdocs/public/] pass through E:/xampp/htdocs/public/index.php
```

Comment: Does 兌 work? What about 䅍 or 儍? (I ask because those kanji have UTF8 codes that differ from the one that breaks only in one byte)

Comment: Also, where is it throwing the exception? Do you have some sort of stack trace that goes with that exception?

Comment: @DanielMartin The kanji 䅍 throws the same error, 儍 works fine. See the edit for the stack trace!

The exception comes from $kanji = Kanji::findById($findKanji);

Comment: I have a suspicion - I suspect that the kanji 儅 will also not work well, but that the stack trace for that kanji will contain a call to `Purple\Controller\ViewController->kanjiAction('\xE5\x84')`. Does it? If so, then I know part of the problem.

Comment: @DanielMartin It does! 兌 returns an exception as well. 儅  returns '\xE5\x84' as you said. 

Is it a bug in phalcon, that causes it?

Comment: @DanielMartin I tried passing the kanji as a GET variable, it works. 免, 䅍, 儍 etc. are encoded correctly. So I am assuming that Phalcon doesn't handle the multibyte strings correctly?

Comment: Phalcon does handle it though, at least on my machine. I think there's something weird going on with the `RewriteRule` directives that phalcon depends on for nice URLs and Apache 2.4 for windows. (I tell how to turn the debug logging on rewrite up in my answer) Under the covers, the `RewriteRule`s in your `.htaccess` files should turn your request for `http://localhost/view/kanji/免` into a request for `http://localhost/public/index.php?_url=/view%2fkanji%2f%e5%85%8d`, and that's when phalcon takes over. I suspect something is going wrong before then.

Comment: @DanielMartin You are right! If you look in the trace at 7th line, you can see that it gets cut off!

Comment: And I updated my answer again. I think this must be a bug in either Apache 2.4 or Apache 2.4 on windows. I don't know what's causing it, but I think my workaround will get you going again.

Comment: @DanielMartin Applied the change, it still unfortunately gets cut off. I will update the question with the new trace.

Comment: Okay, one more try: in both those `RewriteRule`s, change `(.*)` to `((?s).*)`

Comment: @DanielMartin That worked! Awesome, you have been a great help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your stack trace, it appears that something is stripping off part of the `$findKanji` before it reaches your controller. Instead of the three bytes that represent 免, there is only the first of those in the call to `kanjiAction`.

The other kanji that failed also contained a `0x85` byte in it, so I wonder if something before you hit your controller is stripping all bytes once it hits byte `0x85`.

So now you need to see what might be interfering with your parameter before it gets to your controller. Do you have any event listeners attached to `dispatch:beforeDispatchLoop` or to any of the `dispatch` events? (If so, what?)

I will note that I just made a phalcon app from scratch (followed the tutorial) to see the stack trace I'd get and I got the stack trace:

```
Exception: Because I can
 File=/var/www/tutorial/app/controllers/ViewController.php
 Line=15
#0 [internal function]: ViewController->kanjiAction('???')
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/tutorial/public/index.php(39): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#3 {main}
```

Note the three characters being passed to `kanjiAction`: if I hit the url `/view/kanji/%E5` I only get one character.

That was with a simplified controller that existed just to give a stack trace:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class ViewController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
    }

    public function kanjiAction($findKanji = "")
    {
        var_dump($findKanji);
        throw new Exception('Because I can');
    }
}
```

This is using Phalcon 2.0.1. So we know that a vanilla phalcon app passes all three bytes on down to the handler, at least on my setup of ubuntu and Apache 2.2.

Looking at the difference between my setup (that apparently works) and yours, I'm wondering if the difference is something to do with the Apache rewrite rules on Windows. So let's turn the debugging on the rewrite process way up. Since you have Apache 2.4, that's done by putting this directive:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

Into your `<VirtualHost>` section in your server config file.

Once you do that, update the answer with the lines in the apache log that contain `[rewrite:` that are generated when you try to access one of these erroring kanji.

---

EDIT: And now that you've included that information, I think I have a fix.

I don't know why you're seeing the problem that you are. I'm going to separately try to reproduce it so that I can file a bug with apache (though I may not be able to until I get a windows box), but in the meantime I think I have a fix.

First, in the `<VirtualHost>` section in your server config file add this directive:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

Then, assuming that you have your `.htaccess` files set up as in the Phalcon tutorial, add the `B` option to the second `RewriteRule` in the top directory's `.htaccess` file, so that the line looks like:

```
RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [B,L]
```

Then also add the `B` flag to the `RewriteRule` line in the `.htaccess` file in the `public/` directory, so that the line becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [B,QSA,L]
```

That second change *might* not be necessary; since I don't have a system with your exact problem, I can't check.

---

Still no luck, but let's try one more thing: turn `(.*)` into `((?s).*)` so that the lines modified before now read:

```
RewriteRule  ((?s).*) public/$1 [B,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [B,QSA,L]
```

Assuming that this works, the reasoning behind it is bizarre.

Apparently, character 0x85 is a "next line" character in Unicode, and can be treated by PCRE (the regex engine underlying Apache's rewrite functionality) as a newline character, [as detailed here](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/10/PCRE-and-newlines.html). The normal way that PCRE is compiled is to treat only character 10 as a newline, (\n) but PCRE can be compiled to treat more characters as a newline character.

When a character is a "newline" character, the regex metacharacter `.` won't match it, unless the `s` regex option is active. The `(?s)` bit makes that option active.

If this works, you can eliminate the `B` option on the `RewriteRules`, and remove the `AllowEncodedSlashes` directive from your `<VirtualHost>`.

Are you using a locally compiled apache binary, or did you get one from an official place? Because if you got one from an official place, you should complain that them compiling PCRE with this strange option wasted your weekend.

Comment: Last edit works!  
To think it was something like that screwing it up. 
Whether it is official, I cannot answer. I am using XAMPP as a development environment, so I would have to ask them if they are compiling it themselves or if they are using the official one. I will look into it, and make a bug report if necessary. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad this came to a resolution. Sorry it took so long - I should have had my memory tickled about character 0x85 being a newline-ish character sooner; that's something I vaguely knew when reminded of it, but clearly was not something close enough to the front of my head to pull it out.

Comment: I've now reported this to XAMPP; we'll see if anything comes of it: https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=71201